# Discord.js: client.login() promise never resolves, client.on("ready") never fires

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made a very simple Discord bot with discord.js; the bot replies with "Good morning to you too" every time someone sends a message containing the text "good morning". This used to work but I noticed that the bot stopped replying to messages today. My code is below; the bot is hosted on Replit.

```
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require("discord.js");

const intents = new IntentsBitField();
intents.add(IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages, IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent);

const client = new Client({
  intents
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Client ready.");
});

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  try {
    if (message.type === 0 && !message.author.bot) {
      if (message.content.trim().toUpperCase().includes("GOOD MORNING")) {
        await message.reply("Good morning to you too!");
      }
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

When I run this code, the `client.login()` promise never resolves and the `ready` event of the `client` never fires. I have checked for other possible causes, such as the `process.env.TOKEN` being wrong. Any idea what may cause this and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @IDcLuc No, nothing is appearing on the console.

Comment: Can't reproduce: I copy-pasted the code above and it works as expected.

Comment: Is your internet connection good? Is something blocking access to Discord maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because of a ratelimit. Replit is shared IP, making it easier to get ratelimited.

You can check if you are getting ratelimited with the `debug` event. It's a good idea to add this code, outside of any listeners. This will most likely answer why your code may seem to be doing "nothing".

```js
client
    .on("debug", console.log)
    .on("warn", console.log)
```

If you get output, saying you hit a 429, you got ratelimited. Something that usually fixes it is running this in your terminal, then running the code again:

```
kill 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! I was already suspecting it had something to do with Replit but couldn't figure out what it was.